# Git connects to different address than given for origin

Tags: github, unicode

when I use

```
git remote -v
```

I receive

```
origin  git@github.com:user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:user/repo.git (push)
```

Which looks quite fine, but if I then try to

```
git push origin
```

I receive

```
\302\226\302\226git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

After I checked and reassigned the ssh keys for a thousand times I became suspicious about the address and tried

```
git push git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

And it worked like a charm. Any idea where I can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got some Unicode control characters (specifically two U+0096 characters) in your remote URL.  You can fix this by doing this:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

That will set the remote URL to the right thing, and then you should be able to push and pull as normal.